# Поиск нескольких соответствий в искомой строке PHP

Tags: php

хотел реализовать поиск соответствий в искомой строке но с поиском нескольких значений.

Сервер получает тексты в которых могут быть слова "Ночь", "ночь", "Нч", "нч" и если в данном тексте есть одно из слов перечисленных выше он бы выдавал только TRUE или FALSE...

```
$text = $data->text;

if(strpos($text, "Ночь") or strpos($text, "ночь") or strpos($text, "Нч") or strpos($text, "нч") === true){
        echo "TRUE";
    }else{
        echo "FALSE";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таких целей удобно использовать регулярные выражения:

```
// PHP 7
var_dump( chekStr('Ночь') ); // bool(true)

function chekStr(string $str): bool
{
    return preg_match('~^ночь|нч$~iu', $str);
}
```

---

```
// PHP 5
var_dump( chekStr('Ночь') ); // bool(true)

function chekStr($str)
{
    return (bool) preg_match('~^ночь|нч$~iu', $str);
}
```

Comment: Ругается на `: bool`…

Comment: А для версии 5.6 есть какой-то альтернативный способ?

Comment: С поиском разобрался, но не могу додумать как реализовать продолжение скрипта, что бы при `true` он выполнял `$ms->send("Good night!", "141435963", $access_token);`...

Comment: Все работает кроме одного момента, если в тексте есть (Например) "Нч до утра" то он тупо игнорирует его. А вот если заменить его на "Ночь до утра", то скрипт будет выполнятся как нужно. НО, если в тексте просто "Нч" то он тоже будет выполнятся… Как пофиксить?

Comment: Все равно, после замены на указанное вами решение `if(chekStr($data->object->text)){true}else{false}` выдает `false` вместо `true`. Не зависимо от того в каком контексте идёт фраза "Нч".

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93361/discussion-between---and-).

Comment: Лучше использовать `str*` функции...

Comment: @And это для замены их лучше использовать. А тут нужен поиск в строке. UPD: А минус-то зачем поставили? )

Comment: Нативный массив сыграет роль. Если я, не прав, скажите в чем?

Comment: @And т.е., вы предлагаете вместо регулярок юзать массив?

Comment: Совершенно верно! Приь многословном использовании ваши регулярки сожрут неимоверное количество памяти, нежели нативка.

Comment: @And я не говорил, что вы не правы - вариант с массивом возможно так же подойдёт, как один из множества вариантов решения. Мне просто не понятно, зачем ставить минус на решении, на котором есть +35 ? Мне ваши -2 в сравнении с +33 "погоды" не сделают, а вам ваш минус так и останется в вашей репе как -1. ))

Comment: Согласно правилам, вы должны исправить вопрос, чтобы я смог убрать минус с ответа.

Comment: @And что касается "многословного использования", дак об этом речи не было. А для малословного варианта ваш вариант съест куда более памяти.

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь. Нативный вариант, работает быстрее регулярок.

Comment: @And а мне нечего в нём исправлять, он корректен как ясный день :)

Comment: Ну и окей-но, вы могли изменить его в разы правильнее, нежели противоречить

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'это нч не день'; 

if (preg_match('~\b(?:ночь|нч)\b~iu', $str)) { 
echo 'true'; 
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93638/discussion-on-answer-by-------).